# Firebase Database, Cloud Functions, Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, google-cloud-functions

How to restrict `write` access to `/lastmodified` table in database named `/functions-project-12345` only to cloud function, `read & write` access to table `/chat` to everyone

```
/functions-project-12345
    /lastmodified: 1234567890
    /chat
        /key-123456
            username: "Mat"
            text: "Hey Bob!"
        /key-123457
            username: "Bob"
            text: "Hey Mat"
```

Comment: Via Firebase Rules? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: If your question is how the rules configuration should look like, you should ask specifically for that, and post your current (obviously not working) configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Functions run with administrative privileges, which means they bypass the security rules of your database. Knowing that, it is quite simple to secure the database to your requirements:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "chat": {
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen chapter `Authenticate with limited privileges` here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start ?

It might be what you need.

Basically you need to use Admin SDK and initialize it with a specific `uid` and service key. Otherwise (namely, if you access database via reference from event which triggered the function), your function will have the same `uid` (and same access rights) as the client who created the event.